# Statistics normal distrution probability

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

A vending machine dispenses coffee into 8 ounce cups. The amount dispensed into these cups is
normally distributed with a.mean of 7.6 oz and a standard deviation of 0.4 oz.

a) Estimate the probability that the machine will overflow an 8-ounce cup (round your answer to two decimal places)

b) Estimate the probability that the machine will not flow an 8-ounce cup (round your answer to two decimal places)

What I did in here is that for a) I need to find $P(x>8)$ and for b) I need to find $P(x\leq 8)$. After finding their z-values and calculating $(P(z>1)$ for a) and $P(z<1)$ for b, I got a) $0.1587\sim 0.16$  and b) $0.8413 \sim 0.84$ . Am I right? please check my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(a) $X \sim Norm(\mathrm{mean}=7.6, \mathrm{sd}=0.4)$ and you seek $P\{X > 8\},$

Computing this in R statistical software, '1 - pnorm(8, 7.6, 0.4)' returns 0.1586553, which
is consistent with your answer. If you standardized and used normal tables,
you probably got a four-place answer slightly inconsistent with mine because you had to round to two places to use the normal table.

(b) 1 - answer to (a), by the complement rule of probability. Also consistent.

KW: Use of normal tables